# Cant connect my database with php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" "root" "") or die("Unable to connect");
 mysqli_select_db("logindb", $con);
 ?>
```

This is the configuration of the connecting.

```
<?php 
require 'config.php';
 ?>
```

This is where is connect the database to a registration page.

Can you see something wrong? This is the error i get: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"root"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Thanks,
Realcookie

Comment: add a comma after each variable in mysqli_connect

Comment: mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "whatever")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the commas bro. Here is the corrected one

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable to connect");
 mysqli_select_db($con, 'logindb'); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Ye thanks alot. The website opened now but at top i see a warning: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Easy drive\config.php on line 3

Comment: mysqli_select_db($con, 'logindb');

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked :). Im sure you can see from everything thats im a beginning student :D